# Accessing live video stream midway using websockets

Tags: node.js, html, websocket, http-live-streaming

I am using the combination of fragmented mp4 and websockets to stream a live video stream to web browser from where MSE takes over.

I have successfully fragmented into the appropriate fmp4 format using ffmpeg and have checked the data using an mpeg4parser tool. 
Utilising a websocket server, the incoming data is broadcasted to all the browser clients connected via websocket. This works fine for both playback and live streaming(using rtsp stream as the input).

The problem I am facing occurs when a client tries to access the stream midway, i.e, once the ffmpeg stream has started. I have saved the init segment(ftyp + moov) elements in a queue buffer in the websocket server. This queue buffer sends this data to each new client on connection.

I believe this data is sent correctly since the browser console does not throw the 'Media Source Element not found' error. Yet no video is streamed when it receives the broadcasted moof/mdat pairs.

So a couple of questions I would like the answer to are:

1) I have observer that each moof element contains a sequence number in it's mfhd child element. Does this have to start from 1 always, which will naturally not be the case for a video stream accessed midway?

2) Is it possible to view the data in the browser client.js. At present all I can view is that my mediaBuffer contains a bunch of [Object ArrayBuffer]. Can I print the binary data inside these buffers?

3) From the server side the data seems to be sent in moof/mdat fragments as each new data arriving from the ffmpeg output to the websocket server begins with a moof element. This was noticed by printing the binary data in console. Is there a similar way to view this data in client side.

4) Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening? Some fragmented mp4 or ISO BMFF format detail that I am missing.

If any further detail is required for clarification please let me know, I will provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your fragments include a base media decode time. Then set the video tag 'currentTime' to the time of the first fragment received.

Comment: I checked my fragments and I believe they already include a base decode time. 

Inside the moof element, there is a tfdt section which has values of 0,512,1024,3072 etc. for successive fragments
There is a time base used by default in ffmpeg:
12800 tbn, 25 tbc 

I can see this with the aid of the mpeg parser tool and I have understood how to set the video.currentTime in javascript. What I cannot understand is how do I access this decode time value in js? I saw it with the help of the mpegparser tool. Is this decode time accessed using a specific function or element id in client side?

Comment: You can query for buffered regions. Then set video.currentTime the the start of the first region. All the API docs are available at w3c.

Comment: thanks a lot szatmary. The video is playing fine now for both refresh condition and when a new user joins. 

The solution in brief:

There is data buffered in the video source buffer which is played by the videoElement. 
The buffer is accessed using an API video.buffered which returns a TimeRange object. This object contains few parameters including start and end time. 

User accessing the video stream in between his start time will be a positive value other than zero. So we set video.currentTime as the positive value, instructing the video element to play from a valid buffer range.

Comment: @Nishanth would you like to share the code solution of both server and client side? I really appreciate that. Thanks in advance!